# A list of length $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to verify that list $v$ of length $1$ is linearly independent if and only if $v \neq 0$. I just need to confirm that I am correct in the following reasoning:

Let $\text{span}() = \{0\}$. Now suppose we have $v$, a list of length $1$. If $v = 0$, then $\text{span}(v) = {0}$ and $v \in \text{span}()$. Since we don't need any vectors to span $0$, the list is linearly dependent.

**added**:

If $v \neq 0$, then $\text{span}(v) = av$. Th only linear combination $av$ for $a \in \mathbb{F}$ that yields the $0$ vector, is $a = 0$, which demonstrates that the list of length $1$ where $v \neq 0$ is linearly independent.

Additionally:

Would this be a suitable proof?

Comment: What is your definition of linear dependency? The most common one is: A list $L$ of length $n$ is linear independent iff $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i L_i = 0$ implies $a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0$. This definition makes your task almost trivial.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the conventional definition. I guess my reasoning was, if the empty list by itself is independent, and it spans $0$, then it must be that our list of length $1$ is dependent if $v = 0$

Comment: I suppose $a_1v_1 = 0$, where $v_1 = 0$ Is satisfied for any scalar $a_1 \in \mathbb{F}$ would also work?

Comment: As Hurkyl stated, that reasoning is correct –- but you still need to show the converse, namely that $(v)$ is independent if $v \neq 0$. Your second attempt is also valid, but the converse is still not proven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint to prove the converse:**

In the conventional definition set $n=1$. Then $(v_1)$ is linearly independent if and only if $a_1 v_1 = 0$ implies $a_1 = 0$. Why is that the case if and only if $v_1 = 0$? What if $v_1 = 0$? What if $v_1 \neq 0$?

Comment: I added to the proof. Let me know if it is correct

Comment: Yes, the corrected proof is sufficient. Although I could ask -- if I really, really wanted to -- why $a=0$ is the only possibility for a linear combination of the zero vector.

Comment: Well if a scalar and vector are being multiplied together, and we have established that $v$ is non-zero. So in order $av = 0$ to be true, it must be that $a = 0$

Comment: This reminds me of a similar Proof which involved proving that if $a \in \mathbb{F}, v \in V$, and $av = 0$, then $a = 0$ or $v = 0$

Comment: I'm just nitpicking here, but: Why must $a=0$ hold? To clarify my point: It holds because we are computing in a field. What if we were computing in a ring, possibly with zero divisors?

Comment: By the way, this similar proof of yours would also be a solution for your original problem. :)

Comment: Well , the way that I showed that if $a \neq 0$, then $v = 0$,was to show that there was some $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $a^{-1} \cdot a = 1$,which constrained $v$ to $0$. However if $a = 0$, then $a^{-1} \not\in \mathbb{F}$, which means that $v = 0$, in the latter case. I haven't learned much about rings yet, unfortunately

Comment: Okay, that's more or less the point. To show it in exhausting detail: If $v \neq 0$, then $v$ has a non-zero entry, say $v_i$. Since $av = (0,\ldots,0)$, we have $av_i = 0$. However, $v_i$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{F}$ and we obtain $a = a v_i v_i^{-1} = 0 v_i^{-1} = 0$, which is what we wanted to show. Rings yield counterexamples for such reasoning. If you know modular arithmetic, consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. In this ring, $2\cdot2=0$, even though $2 \neq 0$. Elements with this property are called zero divisors.

Comment: I see. I just thought it was weird for $v$ to have an inverse, since it is not explicitly a scalar in a field, but contained in a vector space $V$ over a field

Comment: Be careful, $v$ does not have an inverse! There is an **entry** of $v$ that has an inverse, and this entry is indeed a scalar in a field.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. thanks for the discussion, thats why you got awarded the answer! To be honest, I know next to nothing about algebraic structures such as the ring, group, etc. however, once I finish this textbook in the next couple of months I'm going to pick up another Algebra textbook

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of linearly dependent then is that the span of your list is strictly larger than the span of any sublist? Or, at least, this is a fact you may invoke?)

If so, then you have a correct proof that $\{0\}$ is a linearly dependent set. It remains to be shown that $\{v\}$ is linearly independent if $v \neq 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you caught my question after the edit... my notation was sloppy at first.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was trying to get at. If $()$ by default is linearly independent, and $span() = \{0\}$, then we don't need anymore vectors to span $0$. If it happens that we have one vector in a list, and it only spans $0$, them clearly this list is dependent. It's not really my "go-to" definition for linear independence, as I'm aware of the conventional $a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_nv_n = 0$ where $a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0$ definition.